# Python import error: "encondings" on debian 10

Tags: python, linux, module, debian

So I'm running debian 10, and using python 3.7 (which I built from source). For some reason I can no longer use the CLI interpreter, and whenever I try to execute anything that relies on Python, it returns the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f41b0784740 (most recent call first):
Aborted
```

However, when I run the exact same command (either for the interpreter or when running a different python application) using `sudo`, it works perfectly fine. It feels like the supporting python 3.7 modules are not accessible  by the current user. But I'm not sure how to proceed in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup [locale](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locale.1.html)

For standard UTF-8 en_US you can do:

```
echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/environment
echo 'export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/environment
echo 'export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/environment
echo 'export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/environment
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm getting a different error now after the proposed changes: `This system supports the C.UTF-8 locale which is recommended.
You might be able to resolve your issue by exporting the
following environment variables:

    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8

Click discovered that you exported a UTF-8 locale
but the locale system could not pick up from it because
it does not exist.  The exported locale is "en_US.UTF-8" but it
is not supported`

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the locales, though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a way around this. I updated my python alias to point to `python3.7` instead of `python3`. I am still, however, not sure if this is a solution, or a workaround. But it works now.